# How to right click on one button computer?

Tags: mouse, macintosh

I've installed Linux with Lxde desktop (Lubuntu) on an old G3 iBook. How can I get the right-click functions on a computer that has only got a one button controller?

Comment: Usually this is done Ctrl-Click.

Comment: Some keyboards also have the "Menu" key (keycode 135 in X11)

Comment: And you can switch on *mouse emulation by keyboard* somewhere in your GUI or with `xkbset mousekeys`, then set numlock perhaps, and type on the keypad `-` to select right button, then click with keypad `5`.